# Django Model syncdb creating existing tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

In django model I had a class named `Invitation`.

I execute `manage.py syncdb` table `Invitation` is created.
This is my first table.

But when i create another class named `Image` and execute `manage.py syncdb`

it returns an error.

that `Table UserInvitation already exists`.

Please help me to create the table `Image` using syncdb command.

Models

```
 class UserInvitation(models.Model):

   InvitationID =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   InvitationCode =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
   Email = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   ExpireDate = models.DateTimeField()
   Deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   CreatedDate =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

 class Meta:
    db_table = u'UserInvitation' 

class UserImage(models.Model):
   ImageID =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   UserID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
   FileName =  models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    db_table = u'UserImage'
```

Comment: Probably you have a mistake in models. Like DrTyrsa wrote, please paste models here

Comment: do you change the name of the classes? Please paste the error

Comment: NO i didnot change the name of classes.

Comment: Impossible. You claim to have an error about `Invitation` table but `db_table` is actually `UserInvitation`. Please post actual traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **South** to reflect changes in your database.

syncdb runs commands that create all the tables in the DB, not just the one that you've added.

With South, you should revert your model back to when it only had the UserInvitation class, run the command:

```
python manage.py convert_to_south <name of app>
```

Add back the UserImage class and run the command:

```
python manage.py schemamigration --auto <name of app>
python manage.py migrate <name of app>
```

This would add the userimage table in your database.

Also, the db_table field in the meta classes should be in lowercase, as the table names, when created, are in lowercase (check your db to make sure)

See South documentation: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/